# can we have static block in non static class in java?

Tags: java, static

I have few question about static in java

1. Can we have static block in non static class??If an object of
   that(no-static) class is initialized in some other class,will the
   static block get executed then??
2. If there is a static class having static block and variable( int a =
   3) and  main() method,and it is executed then will the variable
   initialization take place first or static block execution?I know
   that static block gets executed before the main() method.

Comment: yes we can have a static block in non static class. What have you tried yet?

Comment: Static blocks of code are executed when the class is first loaded.

Comment: When you say static class you mean static inner class? Because otherwise there are no static classes.

Comment: well i have not yet discovered inner class...what i mean by static class is this :  static class _classname_ { block of code}

Comment: @Smatik This is impossible without an inner class. "Normal" classes can't be static in Java. ALthough this might be valid syntax. Not sure about that right now.

Comment: Tried it out and the keyword `static` on a "normal" class gives a compile error. How did you think those existed. Have you even tried anything yourself before asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, you cant, try this

```
class Test1 {

    class X {
        static {  <-- compile error: Cannot define static initializer in inner type Test1.X
        }
    }
...
```

X should be static.

Note: I assume we are talking about nested classes, because this is where static modifier is applicable for classes

2) it depends, see this

```
class Test1 {
    static {
        x = 3;
    }

    static int x = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
 }
```

output

```
2
```

but  now

```
class Test1 {
    static int x = 2;

    static {
        x = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

output will be

```
3
```

Static initialization runs only ones during class loading, it happens always before any instance instantiation. Interestingly both static fields initialization and static init block code runs in the same bytecode function with the name `<clinit>`:

```
  static <clinit>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    ICONST_3
    PUTSTATIC test/Test1.x : I
   L1
    LINENUMBER 15 L1
    ICONST_2
    PUTSTATIC test/Test1.x : I
    RETURN
```

Comment: OHkay..thats what i meant by static block...thats the answer to 1. what about 2??

Comment: @Smatik - Why don't you spend 2 seconds creating a test program that will answer question #2?

Comment: But there no print to display 3....how come the output display 3??? also what happens if there was a print statement in static block like static int x= 2; System.out.print(x); .....

Answer (score 3):

Please look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

It's called [static initializer in the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). This code will be executed when JVM loads the class. The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.

**You can't use static code in nonstatic inner classes**:

```
    public class MyClass {

    static {
        System.out.println("static code from nonstatic class");
    }

    class In {
        /* it will not compile
        static {

        }
        */
    }
    static class In2 {
        static {
         System.out.println("static code from static inner class");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

See [Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) in [The Java® Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/) for details about calling order. Simply the static blocks are executed in the order they appear in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Having a static class vs. a normal class does not affect what programming constructs you are allowed to use, but simply controls whether or not the class has access to instance fields/methods of the surrounding class.

Comment: It's not true. I.e. you can't use static code in nonstatic inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can have a static block in a `non-static` class and it is loaded as soon as class loads in JVM

```
public class StaticDemo {

    static{
        System.out.println("already loaded");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

    }

}
```

This outputs `already loaded`

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, the answer can be found in the [Java Language Specification §12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), in particular step 9 of the "detailed initialization procedure":

> Next, execute [...] the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class [...] in textual order, as though they were a single block.

In other words, the `static {}` blocks and the initializer expressions of static fields are executed in the order they appear in the source code - if the static block is before the field declaration then it will run first (and see the default value of the field, typically `null` or 0), if the static block is after the field declaration then it will run second (and will see the value assigned by the initializer expression).